# Sqlite Update Query causing TypeError

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm working on mini Database using Tkinter and Sqlite. For one of my functions I have it set to update any selected tuple from a listbox. I keep getting a type error that I'm hoping someone can help me on.

I've looked over my code both frontend (GUI) and backend(SQLITE) and still I'm unable to figure out what its talking about. I might be over looking something simple.

Back End(Error Included in Code)

```
def update(Model, Serial, type, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Duration, Failure, Comments):

    '''cur.execute("UPDATE Ml SET Model="", Serial="", Type="", Test1="", Test2="", Test3="", Test4="", Duration="", Failure="", Comments="",  where id=?" (Model, Serial, Type, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Duration, Failure, Comments, id))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'''

    conn = sqlite3.connect("Antenna.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE Ml SET Model="", Serial="", Type="", Test1="", Test2="", Test3="", Test4="", Duration="", Failure="", Comments="",  where id=?" (Model, Serial, Type, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Duration, Failure, Comments, id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Front End

```
def update_command():

    result = messagebox.askquestion("Edit Record?", "Are you sure you'd like to change the following record?")
    if result == "yes" and model_text.get() and serial_text.get() and Type_text.get() and Test1_text.get() and Test2_text.get() and Test3_text.get() and Test4_text.get() and duration_text.get() and failure_text.get() and comment_text.get():
        Back_End.update(model_text.get(), serial_text.get(), Type_text.get(), Test1_text.get(), Test2_text.get(), Test3_text.get(), Test4_text.get(), duration_text.get(), failure_text.get(), comment_text.get())
        view_command()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Invalid Selection", "Please Select a item to edit")
```

Comment: This question would be easier to understand if you kept the error separate rather than putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your call to cursor `execute` seems to be full of problems.  Try using this version:

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE Ml SET Model=?, Serial=?, Type=?, Test1=?, Test2=?, Test3=?,
   Test4=?, Duration=?, Failure=?, Comments=?, WHERE id=?""",
    (Model, Serial, Type, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Duration, Failure, Comments, id,))
```

Problems that I see include that you should be using `?` placeholders for the RHS of the update assignments on all columns.  Currently, you are using empty string, which however would result in another error anyway, because you use double instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    '''cur.execute("UPDATE Ml SET Model="", Serial="", Type="", Test1="", Test2="", Test3="", Test4="", Duration="", Failure="", Comments="",  where id=?", (Model, Serial, Type, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Duration, Failure, Comments, id))
```

You missed a comma. Put one just after the string ends and your tuple of arguments begin.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained where the comma is missing, and why that particular comma is important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with @Bryan Oakley, anyway for me the biggest problem is how the sql statement is build.

See below an alternative way that should simplify all the matter.

I've decoupling various part of the statement.

```
table = 'Ml'

fields = ('Model', 'Serial', 'Type', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Duration', 'Failure', 'Comments',)

pk = 'id'

sql = "UPDATE %s SET %s =? WHERE %s =?"%(table," =?, ".join(fields),pk)

args = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,)

args = (*args, 42)

print(sql,args)
```